# Java interface with classes for volume and area of shapes

Tags: java, oop, math, interface, package

I'm a very green thumb to Java and would like to know how to properly use an interface to connect classes.

Say there is an interface X, in package Y for the volume and area of a shape

```
package Y;

public interface Shape {
    public double volume();

    public double surfaceArea();
}
```

Given a class called tetrahedron, where the math for the volume and area are respectively

```
package Y;

public class Tetrahedron implements Shape{
    Tetrahedron(double edge) {
        (volume) Math.pow(edge, 3)/(6*Math.sqrt(2));
        (area) Math.sqrt(3)*Math.pow(edge, 2);
    }
}
```

Which is then once again accessed by the main class, also in package Y

```
package Y;

public class Main {
    static void main(String[] args){
        Shape a = new Tetrahedron(5);
        System.out.println(a.volume());
        System.out.println(a.surfaceArea());
    }
}
```

How exactly would you go about connecting the interface to the second class?
As far as I am aware, you cannot simply override the value of `volume` and `surfaceArea` by doing something such as `volume = x`, so how exactly does one use the interface to get from A to B to C?

Comment: Maybe you should start searching what is an interface for. But to give you a quick info, it is used to force class that implement it to implement all methods described in the interface. So you might want to implement shape on the Tetrahedron class and your IDE will pretty much tell you what to do next.

Comment: My IDE is brain dead. Also I find plenty on what the interface is and what it does, but not how to specifically use it, the examples I find are returning failed results when I attempt to use them

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html).

Comment: Well.. interface is not use to "connect classes", it is use to enforce a signature of your class. So in your case you should just need to do it like this `public class Tetrahedron implements Shape { ...` and the compiler will now force you to implement the methods volume() and surfaceArea(). And by force I mean it will give you error until you make the methods, maybe that's the error you were getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do like this.

```
public interface Shape {
    public double volume();

    public double surfaceArea();
}

public class Tetrahedron implements Shape{
    double edge;
    Tetrahedron(double edge) {
        this.edge=edge;
    }

    @Override
    public double volume(){
         return Math.pow(edge, 3)/(6*Math.sqrt(2));
    }

    @Override
    public double surfaceArea(){
         return Math.sqrt(3)*Math.pow(edge, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you use overriding to get the class access to a specific implementation of said method of the parent/super-class and force the value to take the attributes of said override? None of the documentation I've read even tried to make mention of using overrides, and the one that did wasn't very forward about it or how to properly use it "push an override onto a variable" wasn't very helpful.

So rather than initiating edge within tetrahedron, we initiate it beforehand and instead access it using a pointer?

Noting that the interface is a separate document as my IDE needs it apart from classes

Comment: Tsk, the other person who was talking about polymorphism deleted their post and didn't catch their name. Wanted to pick their brain on that a little. It's amazing how much a simple relevant example can help versus telling someone to look at the same theory documents.